# Submodule - update .gitmodules for specifying a branch name

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-submodules

I have added a submodule to an ADO repository:

.gitmodules

```
[submodule "public"]
    path = public
    url = https://xyz.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/abc/_git/STW-Sol-public
```

Is there a git command to update .gitmodules for specifying a branch name?

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since git 2.22, you can use `git submodule set-branch` for that:

```
git submodule set-branch --branch mybranch public
```

This adds a `branch = mybranch` to your `.gitmodules`. Which you may also add manually, if you'd rather do so.

More information can be found on git-submodule(1).

You may also want to take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18797720/12886326), which elaborates more on what exactly it means to track a branch. Most importantly:

> git submodule add -b is not some magically way to keep everything up to date with a branch. It is simply adds information about a branch in the .gitmodules file and gives you the option to update the submodule object to the latest commit of a specified branch before populating it.